# How would I know iPhone is moving?

Tags: iphone, core-location, accelerometer

Is there any way to find, iPhone movement?. I need to know if iPhone is still i.e its not moving then do some thing or else if iPhone is moving(in vertical or horizontal direction) do some logic.

Do I need to read accelerometer didAccelerate method. Or there is some other way like reading current location (lat/log) values.

[I DON'T have 3GS]

Please suggest which is the best and robust way to read iPhone movement and how to know if  iPhone is still.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot determine if an object is moving or at rest just by acceleration.

Comment: then do I need to use latitude/longitude or calculate altitude?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to use the UIAccelerometer class.  Set the delegate and do some calculations on the accelerometer:didAccelerate delegate message.

The trick is that you will want to set up some threshold values. If there is no sig movement within your range in the x, y, and z axis, the device is not moving.

Of course, slight vibrations will cause value changes, which is why you will need to determine what not moving is for your purposes.